# FFmpeg libavcodec/encode.c not be compile

Tags: android, c++, ffmpeg, cross-compiling, codec

I am trying use ffmpeg in Android to decode and encode H264 video. But when encode, I meet compile error, as follows:

Error:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "ff_alloc_packet2" referenced by "/data/app/.../lib/x86/libavcodec.so"

compile log:

```
...
CC  libavcodec/decode.o
CC  libavcodec/dirac.o
CC  libavcodec/dv_profile.o
CC  libavcodec/error_resilience.o
CC  libavcodec/exif.o
...
```

Not compile liavcodec/encode.o.

configure:

```
  ./configure \
    --prefix="$PREFIX" \
    --disable-stripping \
    --enable-jni \
    --cross-prefix="$CROSS_PREFIX" \
    --target-os=android \
    --arch="$ARCH" \
    --cpu="$CPU" \
    --cc="$CC" \
    --cxx="$CXX" \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --sysroot="$TOOLCHAIN"/sysroot \
    --enable-libx264 \
    --extra-cflags="$OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS -Iexternal-libs/x264/$CPU/include" \
    --extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS -Lexternal-libs/x264/$CPU/lib" \
    $COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS
```

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

#--------------------
# Standard options:
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS=""

# Licensing options:
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-gpl"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-version3"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --disable-nonfree"

# Configuration options:
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --disable-static"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-shared"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-small"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-runtime-cpudetect"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --disable-gray"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --disable-swscale-alpha"

# Program options:
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --disable-programs"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --disable-ffmpeg"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --disable-ffplay"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --disable-ffprobe"

# Documentation options:
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --disable-doc"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --disable-htmlpages"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --disable-manpages"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --disable-podpages"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --disable-txtpages"

# Component options:
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --disable-avdevice"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-avcodec"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-avformat"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-avutil"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-swresample"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-swscale"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --disable-postproc"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-avfilter"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --disable-avresample"

# Hardware accelerators:
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --disable-hwaccels"

# Individual component options:
# export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --disable-everything"

# ./configure --list-decoders
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --disable-decoders"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-decoder=aac"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-decoder=aac_latm"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-decoder=flv"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-decoder=h264"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-decoder=mp3*"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-decoder=vp6f"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-decoder=flac"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-decoder=hevc"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-decoder=vp8"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-decoder=vp9"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-decoder=h263"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-decoder=h263i"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-decoder=h263p"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-decoder=mpeg4"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-decoder=mjpeg"

# ./configure --list-muxers
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --disable-muxers"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-muxer=mp4"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-muxer=mjpeg"

# ./configure --list-demuxers
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --disable-demuxers"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-demuxer=aac"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-demuxer=concat"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-demuxer=data"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-demuxer=flv"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-demuxer=hls"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-demuxer=live_flv"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-demuxer=mov"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-demuxer=mp3"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-demuxer=mpegps"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-demuxer=mpegts"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-demuxer=mpegvideo"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-demuxer=flac"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-demuxer=hevc"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-demuxer=webm_dash_manifest"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-demuxer=mpeg4"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-demuxer=rtsp"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-demuxer=mjpeg"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-demuxer=avi"

# ./configure --list-parsers
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --disable-parsers"

# ./configure --list-bsf
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --disable-bsfs"

# ./configure --list-protocols
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --disable-protocols"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-protocol=file"

export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --disable-devices"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --disable-filters"

# External library support:
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --disable-iconv"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --disable-audiotoolbox"
export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --disable-videotoolbox"
```

Answer (score 0):

I re-download ffmpeg source code, then this problem solved.